# How to get back to the first activity when opening multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app which have HomeActivity and 4 activities A,B,C,D.
I want when clicking on button `start_activity_A_btn` in HomeActivity to star activity A, and A starts B, B starts C, C starts D, then `done` button which takes me to HomeActivity.
NOTICE : in every activity (A,B,C,D) I have some `data` to save and get back to the HomeActivity after pressing `done` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do use the following flag in your intent (please check the link, it explains a similar situation to the one you are facing): [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT). So, in your activity D, in the onClickListener for the done button, here's the code you'd have to use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityAname.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent.putExtra("data", dataYouReceiveFromABCD);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will get your A Activity to resume.

Now, regarding the "data" you will just have to keep accumulating this data in a String using some separator if that's possible (since you haven't told us what this data is exactly), so if it was a username and a password you could separate the two using a random combination of characters that will possibly never occur ("246@$^") and then just keep creating a string that you keep building in A, B, C and D and then finally in D you put that String as an extra in the intent (check the code I've posted above). If it's some other sort of data then you could perhaps serialize it if that helps. However, if you do use a String with a predetermined separator then all you will have to do is in Activity A you will have to use the following code in the onResume() method of Activity A.

```
if(this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("data") != null)
{
  String data = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("data");
  //do some stuff here with that data
}
```

Comment: the data I want to receive is int [], the array will be send from HomeActivity and will have some modifications in every activity A,B,C,D and then the HomeActivity will receive it again

Answer (score 0):

If you need data returning an Activity, you should use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to start ABCD. This works very much like your HomeActivity is opening up some dialog, and once the Activity finished (by pressing done or cancel, depends), you get [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) in your HomeActivity.

Comment: I know this way but I want to close all the tabs and back from D to HomeActivity without passing A,B,C